# Getting OJDBC6 ResultSet#getDate() semantics on OJDBC7

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

We just migrated from to ojdbc6 to ojdbc7 and notice a behavior change in the ResultSet#getDate() semantics. Previously the java.sql.Date return was normalized by setting the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds to zero, but now with ojdbc7 this is no longer happening, java.sql.Date has the hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds set according to the value on the database.

For those who marked it as duplicated: I don't want to know how to deal with this change, my question is right below:

My question is: is there a way to set a ojdbc7 driver property to get the ojdbc6 behavior on that point?

Comment: No SkinnyJ, my question is different! I'm not looking for explanations about why it is behaving like this, but related to how to change the behavior.

Comment: This seems like a bug (which Oracle has not yet acknowledged): https://community.oracle.com/message/13398818#13398818

Comment: The answer to "*is there a way to set a ojdbc7 driver property to get the ojdbc6 behavior on that point?*" **is** in the linked question. It is essentially: "no you can't do it". Oracle decided that it's OK to violate the JDBC specification and they are not going to change it back.

Comment: They have already done changes where, even they considered incorrect, they let you decide the behavior you want to. The mapDateToTimestamp flag is an example of it.

Comment: I know that Oracle did that previously. But apparently they now decided that it's not necessary to supply a way to make the driver compliant with the JDBC specs. I wouldn't be surprised if Oracle is even thinking about changing the JDBC specification to make their driver comply with it - after all they control Java.